# when I scroll and the video goes up or down the screen, it stops. I want the video to continue even though isn't in the screen

Tags: android

I'm building an app for Android using the YouTube API. The video is in a scroll widget, and when I scroll and the video goes up or down the screen, it stops. I want the video to continue even though isn't in the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give more context like what video player you are using, what is the parent view where it is attached etc

Comment: am using VideoView